# Google Image Search : Unfolding image details effect with jquery?

Tags: jquery, image, panel, unfold

I just noticed the nice "new" unfolding effect on Google Image Search when you click on an image. Id like to implement that into my project. Im sure there are already jquery plugins which will do just that. Yet I dunno how this effect may be called in order to do a proper search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very similar to Google's implementation: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/

Comment: Thank you ;) This looks promising